# Programmatically add references to project in VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, reference, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to add a *button* to Visual Studio 2013 Professional to have it automatically add two references to a project?

Background: I'm using VS2013 to write scripts for Unity 3D. Whenever I hit the *"Sync MonoDevelop Project"* action within Unity, it rebuilds the project, and upon opening the project in VS2013 it's missing two references for Unity's DLLs. I need to add these, which is pretty quick to do, but I'm looking to shave a few seconds off here and there if possible.

Thanks

Comment: haven't used VS in a while but doesn't it have a macro recorder that let's you record and play back actions you perform in the UI?

Comment: Why are you hitting Sync MonoDevelop Project so much? What's putting it out of sync?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D - No idea. I haven't seen one, I'll take a look. Thanks!

Comment: @NickUdell - When adding a new script, or imported plugin, or anything like that, into the project in Unity it doesn't immediately show up in VS. So, I hit the Sync button to let it add it to the VS Solution, then refresh the solution .. which blows away my references.

Comment: How are you adding a new script / plugin? From inside of Unity? That should automatically trigger a rebuild, and the rebuild will add the references to the project. Are you opening the solution or the project in Visual Studio?

Comment: @NickUdell - Correct. In Unity, when I add a new script (which is just a .CS file as far as VS knows), it doesn't immediately show up in the Project Explorer pane in VS. So, I hit Sync MonoDevelop Project and close and re-open the project in VS. This works. Is this the wrong way? o.O

Comment: When you add a new script to Unity (by right clicking and creating a new MonoBehaviour, for example), Unity should add it to the project automatically. You might need to hit Refresh in the Solution Explorer for it to show up, though. What happens when you double-click on your newly-created file in Unity? Does it open in Visual Studio?

Comment: @NickUdell - Without refreshing the project, and double clicking the .CS file in Unity it does correctly open in Visual Studio, but not as part of the project. It opens as a miscellaneous file, so it gets confused as to what is and isn't part of the build. Maybe if I refresh the Solution in VS first? Haven't tried that yet, but I'll be able to test it later.

Comment: @NickUdell - Apparently adding the script in Unity does add it to the solution. But the Refresh button on the Solution Explorer in VS doesn't show it in the list. The only way to get it to show is to Close and Re-Open the Solution. Did you want to add anything to this? Or submit an answer for me to mark as the answer? You at least taught me I don't have to keep hitting `Sync MonoDevelop Project` repeatedly. =)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D - FYI they removed Macro Recorder from VS2012 onwards. =(

Comment: darn ... maybe Visual Assist X adds it back in? That tool is pretty much invaluable for VS development either way.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D If I were to submit any of my comments as an answer, it wouldn't answer your actual question, which would be pretty annoying for anybody googling it later. Glad it helped a bit, but best to keep it open until somebody knows.